# Jlabel array not visible in netbeans while creating dynamically

Tags: java, swing

I am not able to view the labels which are created dynamically.The code is as follows :

```
JLabel[] labels = new javax.swing.JLabel[cur.length];
for (int i = 0 ;i < cur.length; i++)
{
   System.out.println("in");
   labels[i] = new JLabel( cur[i] );
    labels[i].setText(""+cur[i]);
   jPanel1.add(labels[i]);
   this.setVisible(true);
   }
 }
```

Comment: 1.) shift this.setVisible after for loop. 2.)Try calling jPanel1.validate()/repaint() after adding lable to it.(May be not needed if you move setVisible at the end.) Also there is an extra closing brace in posted code please remove it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There can one or many of cause for your problem
1. Your JPanel may not be added to Container. Add it using getContentPane().add(jpanel1);
2. Your JLabel itself are not visible. Set their visible property to true.
3. Your JPanel is not having flowlayout but CardLayout and hence they might be visible in the back of other component. Assign the layout using jpanel1.setLayout(new FlowLayout())
4. Shift your this.setVisible(true) to outside loop.

Comment: *"Your JLabel itself are not visible. Set their visible property to true."*  Components added to containers are visible by default.  So no, this is not the cause of the problem. *"Your JPanel is not having flowlayout but GridLayout."*  That would make no difference here.  Either layout can display multiple components.

Comment: Thanks. I missed to write "CardLayout" instead of GridLayout. Please see my Editted point no: 3

Answer (score 0):

What layout are you having for your jPanel object ? try changing its layout to say, FlowLayout. Give it layout in the beginning where you defined it and then use it in your loop.